# multithreading - sharing data

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked the following question in an interview.

> There is an object which is being shared by multiple threads. The object has the following function. How can you make sure that different threads can execute the functions simultaneously for different values of parameter x? If two threads are executing with same value of x, one of them should be blocked.

```
public void func(String x){
-----
}
```

"synchronized" keyword will not work in this case as it will make sure only one thread can execute at a time. Please let me know what will be the solution for this

Comment: My KISS sense wants me to tell you to just make the method `synchronized` and come back to the fancier synchronization when this actually becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: Point taken -- "Your question is dumb" is rarely what an interviewer wants to hear, however!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is something like

```
public void func(String x){
    synchronized (x.intern()) {
        // Body here
    }
}
```

This will behave just as described; of course, it feels like a nasty hack, since the objects being synchronized are publicly accessible, and other code could interfere with the locking as a result.

Comment: And another problem with this solution: it doesn't work with null values of x.

Comment: @EyalSchneider, good point -- although, depending on the full specification, throwing the `NullPointerException` may be a perfectly fine response to a null argument.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap as member variable.

```
private HashMap<String,Lock> lockMap = new HashMap<String,Lock>();
public void func(String x){
    if(lockMap.get(x) == null){
        lockMap.put(x,new ReentrantLock());
    }  
    lockMap.get(x).lock(); 
    ...
    ...  
    lockMap.get(x).unlock(); 
}
```

Comment: Check out the `ConcurrentMap` interface, especially its `putIfAbsent()` method.

Comment: Erickson, Yes. Above code can be optimised.I tried to focus on logic.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Probably the interviewer was interested in the solution proposed by  Ernest Friedman-Hill. However, due to its disadvantages, it usually can't be used in production code. Once I wrote the following synchronization utility to handle this problem:

```
package com.paypal.risk.ars.dss.framework.concurrent;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class MultiLock <K>{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<K, ReentrantLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, ReentrantLock>();  

    /**
     * Locks on a given id.
     * Make sure to call unlock() afterwards, otherwise serious bugs may occur.
     * It is strongly recommended to use try{ }finally{} in order to guarantee this.
     * Note that the lock is re-entrant. 
     * @param id The id to lock on
     */
    public void lock(K id) {
        while (true) {
            ReentrantLock lock = getLockFor(id);
            lock.lock();
            if (locks.get(id) == lock)
                return;
            else // means that the lock has been removed from the map by another thread, so it is not safe to
                 // continue with the one we have, and we must retry.
                 // without this, another thread may create a new lock for the same id, and then work on it.
                lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unlocks on a given id.
     * If the lock is not currently held, an exception is thrown.
     *  
     * @param id The id to unlock
     * @throws IllegalMonitorStateException in case that the thread doesn't hold the lock
     */
    public void unlock(K id) {
        ReentrantLock lock = locks.get(id);
        if (lock == null || !lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
            throw new IllegalMonitorStateException("Lock for " + id + " is not owned by the current thread!");
        locks.remove(id);
        lock.unlock();
    }

    private ReentrantLock getLockFor(K id) {
        ReentrantLock lock = locks.get(id);
        if (lock == null) {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            ReentrantLock prevLock = locks.putIfAbsent(id, lock);
            if (prevLock != null)
                lock = prevLock;
        }
        return lock;
    }
}
```

Note that it could be implemented in a simpler manner with a simple map and a global lock. However, I wanted to avoid global locks, in order to improve the throughput.